# How to load ipa file with Transporter to app store? "Build" is empty

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, app-store

I'm created Xamarin Forms app for iOS. I'm new to development for iOS and I have problem with publish my app to App Store.

This is my user case:

1. I created certifications and profiles.
2. I created new app in App Store.
3. I created ipa file in Visual Studio.
4. I loaded ipa file to App Store with [Transporter](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784?mt=12). Appliction Loader is not supported now.
5. Load was successful. But when I open appstoreconnect and open my app "build" section is empty.
   Where is the file(file) that I sent?

I can not send this file again. I get an error that you need to change the version. I am changing the version, sending the file but again I can’t see it in my application(on appstoreconnect "My app").

What am I doing wrong? any advice?

Comment: first, you will get an e-mail from Apple after your uploaded binary has been tested.  This should happen within a few minutes.  Next, you can create a new version of your app and select the binary that you uploaded in the build section.

Comment: Be patient, you have to wait until the file appears. It may take several hours sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. Transported have status successful, but i have message to email with current issue. I need to immediately check the mail, I forgot about it.